# Freenas 11 + samba4 AD DC - Can't contact LDAP server

Tags: active-directory, ldap, samba, server-message-block, truenas

I have a fresh 'FreeNAS-11-MASTER-201706070410 (7b5c3aa)' installation + AD DC is on CentOS 6 + samba4 & authenticates Windows 7-10 machines ok. The ad scheme is very simple, all users are in one default ou=Users. I'm trying to configure Freenas through the web interface.

I've created an smb share & it is accessible on the network, but I have to set 'allow guests' in freenas to access it as AD authentication doesn't work yet.

Also, on the Services -> SMB I've changed 'WORKGROUP' to 'XYZ' (domain name in CAPS without '.com'). Also tried with com & lowercase letters.

```
Auxiliary parameters:  //tried with & without them
workgroup = XYZ
realm=xyz.com
```

Freenas network config :

```
Hostname: fs
Domain: xyz.com
IPv4 Default Gateway: 192.168.199.8 //router
IPv6 Default Gateway:     //empty
Nameserver 1: 192.168.199.6    //dc
Nameserver 2:    //empty
Nameserver 3:    //empty
```

On AD DC I've created a user: 'freenas01' & added him to 'Domain Admins' group.

Created machine 'fs' & gave 'full control' security permissions to 'freenas01' user on it.

Trying to setup an Active Directory authentication for an smb share.

In Directory->Directory Service->Active Directory

```
Domain Name (DNS/Realm-Name): xyz.com
Domain Account Name: freenas01
Domain Account Password: xyz12345
Enable: checked
```

When I click save I get: '{'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"}' error.

Trying to figure out how to correctly fill in the following fields in Advanced:

```
User Base: cn=Users,dc=xyz,dc=com
Group Base:     //empty
Site Name:  Default-First-Site-Name
Domain Controller:  192.168.199.6
Global Catalog Server:  192.168.199.6:389     //without 389 port I get additional error: 'Invalid Host/Port: [Errno 61] Connection refused'
Kerberos Realm:    //tried empty & tried creating one on a kerberos realms tab(see below) & then setting it here, no luck.
AD timeout:  60
DNS timeout: 60
Kerberos Principal:    //empty
Idmap backend: rid
Winbind NSS Info: rfc2307
SASL wrapping: plain
Enable: checked
NetBIOS name: fs
NetBIOS alias:    //empty
```

Kerberos realms tab:

```
Realm:  xyz.com
KDC: 192.168.199.6:88
Admin Server: 192.168.199.6
Password Server: 192.168.199.6:464
```

When I click save it doesn't say anything about ports, but I'm not sure about Admin Server not having port or others having them :(

I also tried configuring LDAP on a LDAP tab, but I get 'Notice: samba extensions not detected. CIFS authentication to LDAP disabled' error.

```
Hostname:  192.168.199.6
Base DN:  dc=xyz,dc=com
Bind DN:  cn=freenas01,cn=users,dc=xyz,dc=com
Bind password: xyz12345
Enable: checked
```

I have no encryption enabled, no LDAPS & etc.

Please help.

Docs used:

https://doc.freenas.org/11/directoryservice.html
https://www.mai-hawaii.com/FreeNAS-AD/FreeNAS_9.3.x_setup#Setting_up_Active_Directory_.26_CIFS

Comment: Is it working? I have the same problem